# Ошибка при сборке docker образа

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Всем привет.
Птыаюсь собрать образ ASP.NET Core решения, состоящего из 3 проектов.

В корневой папке у меня 3 проекта (Common, Data, Web)
DockerFile кидал и в корень этих 3 проектов и в папке Web.

Но при сборке командой "docker build -t name ." получаю ошибку

> [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "IPN.IPCP.Web/IPN.IPCP.Web.csproj":
> #12 3.202   Determining projects to restore...
> #12 3.209   Skipping project "/src/IPN.IPCP.Common/IPN.IPCP.Common.csproj" because it was not found.
> #12 3.209   Skipping project "/src/IPN.IPCP.Data/IPN.IPCP.Data.csproj" because it was not found.
> #12 3.214   Skipping project "/src/IPN.IPCP.Common/IPN.IPCP.Common.csproj" because it was not found.
> #12 3.214   Skipping project "/src/IPN.IPCP.Data/IPN.IPCP.Data.csproj" because it was not found.
> #12 71.15 /src/IPN.IPCP.Web/IPN.IPCP.Web.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package APRF.DialConnector.Client. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
> #12 71.15 /src/IPN.IPCP.Web/IPN.IPCP.Web.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package APRF.DialConnector.Contract. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
> #12 71.36 /src/IPN.IPCP.Web/IPN.IPCP.Web.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'NReco.VideoConverter 1.1.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
> #12 71.49   Failed to restore /src/IPN.IPCP.Web/IPN.IPCP.Web.csproj (in 1.13 min).

Код докерфайла следующий:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Web/Web.csproj", "Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Web/Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Web"
RUN dotnet build "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

Что делаю не так ?

Comment: начните со сборки без докера, а как получится — переходите к докеризации.

Comment: на вскидку тут несколько проблем: `Skipping project` - у вас не правильный Dockerfile, оно не находит проекты, библиотека `NReco.VideoConverter` не работает на .net core, только .net framework

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin однако без докера прокт собирается

Comment: @ExplodingKitten да, вот только понять не могу где ошибка в докфайле. А вот на счет конвертора... странно что вне докера проект собирается и заводиться в принципе без проблем. Но попробую и без этой либы

Comment: проблема с докерфайлом в том, что вы копируете только web проект, но пропускаете common и data